# How to fit regression lines on each non-diagonal segment of a pairplot, while retaining breakdown of data points by hue

Tags: python, regression, seaborn, pairplot

I have made a pairplot using the Iris dataset using the code below, but the regression lines show for each of the three iris flowers, rather than for the dataset as a whole (which is what I am looking for). I want each segment of pairplot to color each data point according to which category of Iris it came from, but I want the regression line to be for the whole sample rather than having three separate regression lines within each segment. Is this possible?

(df is my DataFrame created from a downloaded .csv file for the dataset.)

```
iris_pairplot = sns.pairplot(df, hue = "variety", palette="Dark2", height=3, aspect=1, corner=True, kind="reg")
iris_pairplot.fig.suptitle("Pairplot of traits for full Iris sample", fontsize = "xx-large")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('iris_pairplot.png')
```

[image: Iris pairplot]

I have tried to use .regplot() but that seems to be for individual scatterplots as opposed to a pairplot?

Answer (score 2):

Creation of a pairplot with the regression line for all data (not split by hue) is not automatically possible within pairplot. You will need to create the pairplot first without the `kind='reg'` option, which will plot the plot without the lines.

Then, you can take each of the individual subplots within this excluding the diagonal subplots using `map_offdiag()`, which will give you each of the subplots. Note: I get iris with the column as `species`, not `variety`... you may need to rename the column. You can plot the regression line there for each of the subplots. Hope this is what you are looking for...

```
df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
## Note, removed kind=reg"
iris_pairplot = sns.pairplot(df, hue = "species", palette="Dark2", height=3, aspect=1, corner=True)#, kind="reg")
iris_pairplot.fig.suptitle("Pairplot of traits for full Iris sample", fontsize = "xx-large")

## Define function to plot a single regression line
def regline(x, y, **kwargs):
    sns.regplot(data=kwargs['data'], x=x.name, y=y.name, scatter=False, color=kwargs['color'])

## Call the function for each non-diagonal subplot within pairplot
iris_pairplot.map_offdiag(regline, color='red', data=df)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]